# Why aren't I getting any email addresses in my Meteor user object?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm using Meteor 1.0 with accounts-google login service.

I request these permissions

```
requestPermissions:
  google: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
  ]
```

After successful login and when I look at the user object in the Mongo shell on the server I am not seeing any emails at all anywhere in the User document.

I am under the impression that Meteor will store whatever email address was used to login to Google somewhere.

How do I get the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I needed to ask for the permission:

`"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"`

Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have u publish your emails field to client ?

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.publish('', function () {
        if (this.userId)
            return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId }, { fields: { services: false } });
        else
            return this.stop();
    });
}
```

Comment: No I haven't yet but that's not the problem I'm having.  The problem is that the data in the database doesn't have the emails.  Can't publish something that doesn't exist.